# How to get originating context of helper in handlebars?

Tags: handlebars.js, mustache

I am creating a custom helper.

If I use my new helper within an object like this:

```
{{#data}}
    {{newHelper}}
{{/data}}
```

How do I access the data object from my helper function?

I know I can do

```
args.data.root['data']
```

But I want to access it dynamically because it wont always be within an object called 'data', it could be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the current context with `this`

So instead of using `args.data.root['data'].value` you can simply use `this.value`

Comment: Thanks, me, I keep googling this and arriving here. I always forget about this.